# Oven elements don't heat, though electrical continuity and voltage exists

Tags: electrical, oven

I have a leisure (range type) cooker. However the left hand oven has stopped heating up. When I turn the dial I get 230v at each element but no heat is produced. I have checked continuity on both elements and they are fine. After turning on, I have 230v at each element. Both top and bottom.

I have disconnected both elements and used a mains 13a fly lead to test both elements and they both get hot that way. To test the thermostat, I turned the oven on and applied a blow torch to the back of the thermostat probe. When it became hot it isolated the supply to the elements. So I know the thermostat works as well.

Running out of options!!! The model for the cooker is a CM10FRC leisure cooker. Built in 2004. Also, living in the UK hence 230 volts

Comment: Judging by your references to 230V and 13A, I'd guess you're in the UK - It would be good if you could edit your question to include your location.

Comment: When you measured "230V at each element", were you measuring across the terminals of the element or from a common/neutral point to the element?

Comment: Volts don't matter if there's no amps.  :-)

Comment: You're braver than me using a mains fly lead if the terminals are as exposed as the ones I've seen before. Where are you measuring the 230V to? Ground - could mean a dodgy neutral? Or the other side of the element connector?

Comment: I've measured from each side of the element to earth and each side gives me 230v. If I remember correctly, when I tested directly across each element whilst live I didn't get a reading. I've not tried testing between the incoming neutral and the element for a reading. If I don't get continuity there, I'm guessing that's a break down in the conductor? (Insulation resistance?)

Comment: [This thread](https://www.ukwhitegoods.co.uk/forumsphpbb3/leisure-cookmaster-100-cm10frc-t64497-15.html) talks about a thermal cut-off switch ("Item 477 on the blowout. Looks like a little square under the controls."), and "a brown wire attached to a metal plate" (the neutral?). Other than that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Since the heating elements seem ok, check their sockets for wear. Start replacing the low-cost parts first, such as the thermal cut-off mentioned by Mazura, then the adjustable thermostats, etc. Right now we can only offer suggestions.

Comment: You'll get a reading between the incoming neutral and the element supply if your getting it between the element and earth. I'm thinking there's a break in the neutral connection to the elements because you've got 230V both sides of the element. This could be damage or could be a thermal trip device